# What happens if I call EF Reload on a deleted entity?

Tags: entity-framework, entity-framework-6

I'm trying to implement optimistic concurrency,

```
while (true) {
    var e = db.MyTable.FirstOrDefault();
    try {
         // make changes to e
         db.SaveChanges();
         return;
    } catch (DBConcurrencyException ex) {
         db.Entry(e).Reload();
         if (e == null) return;    // <===  this can't be right?!
    }
}
```

what happens if, while I am making changes to e, another job removes the row from the database.  What will happen?  Will SaveChanges succeed?

Or what if prior to the Reload, another job deletes the row?  Will the Reload set e to null in that case?  Or will the Reload throw an exception?  I scrubbed the documentation, but can't find any hint.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`SaveChanges` cannot succeed - row is no longer here so nothing to update. If by succeed you mean it will silently continue, then also not - it will throw `DbUpdateConcurrencyException` (note, **not** `DBConcurrencyException` you catch in your example).

If you `Reload` deleted entity, it will have a state of `Detached` (`db.Entry(e).State`). Method call cannot set your `e` variable to null, even in principle - it's not passed by `ref`.